# Часть кода не исполняется! Ошибку не вызывает!

Tags: c#

Цикл FOR не исполняется, зразу идет `ReadKey()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может надо i < 11?

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом, вопрос можно редактировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в цикле условие для выполнения **i > 11**, но у вас **i = 0**, и проверка условия даст false, т.к. 0 явно не больше 11.